# Inserting word into string

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a string `(4_HEATING_1 = (2)) AND (4_DRYER_1 > (7))` and I  would like to change the numbers enclosed in brackets to make the string look like   `(4_HEATING_1 = Step (2)) AND (4_DRYER_1 > Step (7))`.

Note the `=` might be `<`, `>`, `<>`, `<=` or `>=` and that the number in the bracket can be any number.

I have tried

```
sed -e "s/\(.*\)\(([0-9])\)/\1 Step \2/g"
```

but this only produces
`(4_HEATING_1 = (2)) AND (4_DRYER_1 > Step (7))`.

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ foo='(4_HEATING_1 = (2)) AND (4_DRYER_1 > (7))'
$ printf "%s\n" "$foo" | sed 's/([0-9][0-9]*)/Step &/g'
(4_HEATING_1 = Step (2)) AND (4_DRYER_1 > Step (7))
```

Comment: That works great, thank you so much for the quick response, been trying for ages

Comment: Pleased to have been of service.  Since this answered your question, please click the grey check to the left to mark it as answered so that people can see the problem has been solved.  Welcome to U&L!